# How can i add adview to app programatically?

Tags: adview

I am using the blueprint provided by Jahir fiquitiva on github to make icon pack. I want to put banner ad in this app. I think that the only way to put ad is adding adview programatically. So, please tell me how to add adview programatically rather than adding adview to mainactivity.xml

Link to that app :-
https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/Blueprint